# Google Analytics 4 reports less visits

Tags: google-analytics

I'm comparing the traffic between Universal Analytics (the old one) and Google Analytics 4 (the new one). As I can see, according to UA, today 134 users visited my website. However, according to GA4, only 70 users visited the site.

Should I change something to the HTML? I'm using this code to track the users:

```js
if(!(window.doNotTrack === "1" || navigator.doNotTrack === "1" || navigator.doNotTrack === "yes" || navigator.msDoNotTrack === "1")) {
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-123456789', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

Into the dashboard, GA4 says I have to complete the configuration. I just want the basics, like I had in UA. It says that the configuration assistant is connected to the old property, and it says "transfering data...". However, I don't know whay today it shows 70 users instead of 134.

What should I do? Thank you.